# Mapping between two databases that have different designs

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, migration, mapping

I have a database with a structure, and I need to import the data from this database to other new database, but the new database has a completly different design. For example, the old database have just one table for users and new database  have a customer and a webmaster tables that have FK with the user table.

To PHP, I'm looking for a pattern to write the import/mapping, I'm not sure even the name of it.

Comment: Your problem seems quite specific although the question sounds broad. Naive way to import: Get the data from the old db in PHP, transform/rewrite it in new pattern, insert in the new db. If you want to use the dbs side by side, you'll probably have to write two db handlers and a model to support both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ETL (extract-transform-load) tool is one solution.  ETL is commonly used in data warehousing where you need to extract data from one source, transform it, and load it into a database.